# Flutter Firebase is throwing an error when I intentionally enter the wrong password or email

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

When I entered the wrong password or email, the code didn't throw the correct exception error, such as 'incorrect password' or 'non-existent email,' but instead, it threw a different exception.
this is my code for login ;

```
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Future<void> login() async {
    try {
      await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text,
        password: passwordController.text,
      );
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => SignUp_Screen(),
        ),
      );
      // The login was successful, you can perform any necessary actions here.
    } catch (error, stackTrace) {
      debugPrint(error.toString());
      utils().toastMessage(error.toString());
    }
  }
```

Login button.

```
RoundButton(
                      title: "Login",
                      onTap: () {
                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          login();
                        }
                      },
                    ),
```

Restarted application in 5,257ms.
fl`utter: [firebase_auth/INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS] Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information., NSUnderlyingError=0x600000e9e460 {Error` Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" `UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000ea31e0 {Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data={length = 224, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 ... 5d0a2020 7d0a7d0a }, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8}},`

```
FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
flutter:     code = 400;
flutter:     errors =     (
flutter:                 {
flutter:             domain = global;
flutter:             message = "INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS";
flutter:             reason = invalid;
flutter:         }
flutter:     );
flutter:     message = "INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS";
flutter: }}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`FirebaseAuthException`** to catch exceptions for Authentication:

```
static Future<void> test() async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: "random@gmail.com", password: "password");
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Exception : ${e.code}");
    }
  }
```

[image: DEMO]

Comment: where can I user the above code in button or in the above login method

Comment: It's working. Check my update answer with screenshot.

Comment: ok thank you . it work