# Flutter firebase authentication try-catch not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm creating an application with Flutter and I am using authentication via Firebase email and password. I noticed that by carrying out the code below the exceptions they are not managed or captured by the Try-Catch but the execution is blocked. The function is executed through a SignIn() function used in the onPressed event of a TextButton.

```
Future<void> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      {required String email, required String password}) async {
    try {
      UserCredential credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

The error that is shown to me is the following

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Max4U.png)

I'm utlilizing the following versions:

- Flutter: 3.16.5
- Dart: 3.2.3
- Firebase_core: 2.24.2
- Firebase_auth: 4.15.3

I would like to be able to read and manage the exceptions of the Firebase method. My tests inserted a recorded email and inserted an incorrect password obtaining the error. This is also presented with unregistered or malformed email

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77365067/21590733

Comment: It doesn't work, the exception always occurs and blocks the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58720721/21590733

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<void> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    {required String email, required String password}) async {
  try {
    UserCredential credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    print("FirebaseAuthException: ${e.message}");
  } catch (e) {
    print("Unexpected error: $e");
  }
}
 // Try this .'on FirebaseAuthException' will help you to catch the exception related to firebase authentication.
```